# Charles Proxy Suddenly Stopped Detecting Localhost

Tags: windows, charles-proxy

I've been using Charles for years without a problem, but after taking a few days off Charles has stopped responding to local host requests. All other request work, but anything to do with localhost is toast.

I've seen answers stating that I can use localhost.charlesproxy.com, but that means changing a lot of config files and having to no remember "oh yeah, I can't use localhost:3000 any more, I gotta use localhost.charlesproxy.com:3000 now". It's not the end of the world, but it's a little annoying.

I've looked into `Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Proxy Server - Advanced` and nothing seems out of the ordinary.

[image]

I disabled my firewall

[image]

Made sure that Charles is allowed to communicate through the Firewall (even though it's disabled)

[image]

I've uninstalled / reinstalled Charles a number of times and deleted the app settings found in `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Charles` but Charles still has no love for localhost requests... On the other hand, Fiddler can handle the localhost requests, but I'm much more comfortable using Charles and it's UI.

One last thing, it's probably not worth mentioning, but I've noticed that Charles doesn't list `/sandman` requests anymore. Fiddler does, but a quick and cursory google search doesn't provide any details as to what that request does or if it's important. But I thought I'd mention it because it did stand out to me...

So yeah, does anyone have any idea where else I could look to get Charles up an running again? If I can't use Charles daily, I'll have a tiny, flower vase shaped hole in my heart...

Comment: Did you get a fix to this?.. in the same position :|

Answer (score 0):

I've also been struggling with this, probably happened around the same time too. I will update this answer with any more I discover, but for now I've found a firefox fix:

Set `network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` to `true` in about:config

I suspect all the major browsers released a modification at the same time.

**References**

1. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1535581